# VSE limited to 32 channels?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm putting together a music video with Blender.

I've noticed I can't move my strips higher than channel 32 in the stack.

I'm surprised, becasue there isn't any visible information that there is any limit. I tried finding some option for that in the User Preferences to no avail.

Is there a way to rise this limit?

[image]

Comment: Try collapsing some of your stacked effects into Meta-strips. That should mean that you can get more channels into the 32 available on the main timeline. You can also use another VSE timeline from an alternate scene, as a scene strip. This will come in as a single strip but not as easy to edit timing wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i have searched, u might have to try changing the source code....
Look in content in the below posted link:
Hope you find your answer.
https://developer.blender.org/T42194